# Stopping or at least slowing down the Draw

Tags: madden-12

In my Madden history I usually have stout defensive play, but in this years release (Madden 12) I am having a lot of trouble with shotgun formation draw plays. I just can't seem to stop online opponents from gaining at least four yards per carry. Even if I know the play is coming, I can't seem to slow them down. I am using a 3-4 defense (Ravens, Steelers, Packers, etc). I pinch my D-Line and user a LB that is the QB spy while running 2-Deep man coverage. Occasionally if I sense the Draw play I can hit the hole quickly with the LB and attempt to make a play in the backfield, but it seems like most of the time my lineman and linebackers just get manhandled.

Does anyone have any advice to help stop or slow down the draw play? Formations, coverage assignments, user position selection, etc.

Comment: Is this against online opponents? (Strategy questions usually are, but there is a difference in approach against the AI.) Do you use base 3-4 or 4-3 defense? What team do you play with, or does this happen no matter what team you use? What personnel does the opponent have: split backs, 3/4 WR? Does this include all shotgun runs, or is it only delayed runs that give you problems?

Comment: It is against online opponents. I usually use a 3-4 defense, Ravens, Steelers, Packers, etc. I am usually burned when my opponent is in shotgun formation with at least 1 TE on the line. It just seems like the AI controlling my other players likes to run directly into a blocker and usually on the opposite side of the intended hole created by the blockers (Which is great AI design for run blocking, and a drawback to the defensive AI) Seems like the blocker always gets better position and my defenders never get square and play the RB movement. I don't even know if there is a fix for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the 3-4 over formation with man coverage and play as a safety. Let your LBs take on open blockers and then run through the open line and make a tackle on the RB. Be careful though, this strategy will work great against keeping the draw to only a few yards (or negative yards) but if your opponent catches on they will have an easy time throwing the ball over you deep down field.

Comment: Going to try it out quick and I will come back and let you know if it worked for me.

Comment: Alright, tried it out in practice mode. Tried a standard 3-4 man coverage usering a MLB like I usually do. The CPU average yards gained on 20 attempts was just under 8 yards per carry. I tried 3-4 over man usering the SS and CPU average yards per carry was about 2. I had a  few five yard loss tackles too. I can see what you were saying about online opponents catching on though. If my opponent was creeping up with their safety I would audible to a PA pass over the top every time.